# How to compute the following integral in complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let $C$ denote the unit circle centered at origin in $\mathbb{C}$. Then $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C|1+z+z^2|\,dz$$  where the integral is taken anti-clockwise in along $C$, equals what?

Well I start with putting $z = e^{i \theta}$, $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$. Then $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C|1+z+z^2|\,dz = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{3+2\cos(\theta)}\,  e^{i \theta} \,i\, d \theta$$

Am I going in the right manner? How do I proceed further?

Comment: Have you tried writing $e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta$ and computing the two resulting integrals separately?

Comment: please check something called `residue theorem`

Comment: @MoonKnight How does one apply the residue theorem to evaluate the integral of interest??

Comment: @Sobi How does your suggestion facilitate a way forward??

Comment: @MarkViola Sorry, my bad. I did not notice the absolute value part. It is not an analytic function, so `residue theorem` does not apply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that on $|z|=1$ we have $\bar z=1/z$.  Hence on the unit circle

$$\begin{align}
|1+z+z^2|&=\sqrt{(1+z+z^2)\,\overline{(1+z+z^2)}}\\\\
&=\sqrt{\left(1+z+z^2\right)\left(1+\frac1z+\frac1{z^2}\right)}\\\\
&=\sqrt{\left(\frac1z+1+z\right)^2}\\\\
&=|2\cos(\theta)+1|\tag1
\end{align}$$

Using $(1)$, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z|=1}|1+z+z^2|\,dz&=i\int_{0}^{2\pi}|2\cos(\theta)+1|\cos(\theta)\,d\theta\\\\
&=i\left(\sqrt 3+\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)
\end{align}$$